# Are there any CiviCRM loyalty/rewards extensions available?

Tags: extension

Has CiviCRM been extended to support a loyalty/rewards program for donors?
I searched the CiviCRM forum and found this question has been asked before, but there has been no response from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: there are no available extensions for loyalty or rewards for past actions.

Background / longer answer: Loyalty or rewards programs are typically used by sellers to get buyers coming back and buying more. CiviCRM is designed for not-for-profit organisations, not as a CRM for regular e-commerce sites, so there has been little effort put into this.

However, it's possible to integrate modules from the CMS to create programs along these lines.

One very specific use case: There is a CiviDiscount extension that can be used to reward people who have joined as members with discounts on events, for example.

A second very specific use case: Premiums can be used to incentivize users to make larger donations/buy more expensive memberships by allowing them to claim a gift (eg a mug or T-shirt) if they donate more than a specific amount (eg >$100 or >$250).

Answer (score 3):

This may not be exactly what you were after, but CiviCRM does have the ability to add "premiums" to contribution pages as a reward to donors. For example, "Donate $20 and get a coffee mug".

[From the book](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/premiums/):

> **Premiums**
>
> Configure premiums, such as T-shirts or subscriptions, that you want to offer on your contribution pages:
>
> 1) Navigate to **Administer > CiviContribute > Premiums** (Thank-You Gifts).
>
> 2) You can edit an existing premium or click **Add Premium** to add a new one.
>
> 3) Once you edit or add a premium, you can then enter additional information: Name, Description, SKU (an optional product code), Premium Image (an optional image of the item), Minimum Contribution Amount to receive the premium, Market Value of the premium, Actual Cost, and Options (e.g., colors and sizes).
>
> 4) If you're offering a subscription or service, you can also click on the **Subscription** or **Service Settings** and define additional information here, such as Period type (e.g., Fixed or Rolling), the Fixed Period Start Day, the Duration, and the Frequency.

Comment: Updated URL: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/premiums/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the "Premiums" feature on contribution pages. This allows you to offer your donors/members different gifts or incentives when they sign up or donate.
http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/contributions/setup/

Comment: Updated URL: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/premiums/