# CiviMember - Adding a premium when recording a membership payment

Tags: civimember, premiums

Our organization wants to be able provide gifts to members who sign up for a magazine subscription. We are using CiviMember to record those contacts who sign up for such a subscription. When we click on **Add Membership** in the contact record's "**Memberships**" tab and then select the "**Record Membership Payment**" checkbox, we would like to have the ability to select a premium through the administrative interface like [the way this is available on a front-facing donation page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/701/are-there-any-civicrm-loyalty-rewards-extensions-available).

For qualifying members, we want to present them with gifts based on the subscription amount and also record this for future reference. This type of recording of a subscription is done offline by our staff. Is this somehow possible via an extension or is there some coding/hook required to make this functionality work?

Comment: Hi, does anyone have some idea regarding this? Does our organization need to resort to some custom coding to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If these are new subscriptions only then you can create a price set where one price field contains the subscription fee and another the gifts on offer.  The back office staff would select the premium at the same time as they record the subscription payment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to record this information for renewing as well as new memberships then you could create a custom field (radio would be my preference) containing the gifts on offer.  Provided you make the custom field searchable this will let you search for "all contacts who are getting Gift A" and create mailing labels if gift A in actually something you need to post out.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your staff use the front-end form. Append `&cid=0` to the end of the url and they will be able to create & pay for a membership for someone else.